# Do i need to link to legacy account in admob?

Tags: admob

I have just created my account on AdMob two days ago. It is notified "On August 31, 2014, legacy AdMob will no longer be available.  If you would like to import your legacy AdMob data into your new AdMob account, you first need to link your legacy account to your new account. Click Link account to get started."

Do I need to update my account? Is my account legacy? Do i need to click on "link to legacy account"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recently created your AdMob account you do not need to link or do anything about this matter. You do not have a legacy AdMob account.

This information is for those who used AdMob before they started using their "new" system.

Comment: Thanks..Inside account settings in Payments tag or Payment setting tab i don't see anything ..its blank..why it is blank?

Comment: same for billing and billing setting tab..its blank

Comment: You still have to set up your Payment and Billing settings for your "new" AdMob account. I guess if you haven't gotten any payments or bills yet, there might not be much information. For Billing I get "Billing account setup".

Comment: thanks..i have not published any app till now..so it might show the billing setings or payment settings only when i publish my app and link to admob account..also do i need to publish my app before linking  my app to admob or should i link my app to admob before publishing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "link". On AdMob you create a "ad unit", and then use your ad unit ID in your app code to show the ads from AdMob. I think you can create the campaign first, and the app after. Both ways work, but to have ads in your first version you would need to have a AdMob ad unit ID already.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob  This link provides information about how to add ads in my app through admob..should I follow these steps before publishing my app or i can follow these steps only after publishing my app?

Comment: I would try doing them before publishing, to have ads in your app when you release it.

Comment: okay..thanks...:)..and once i will follow these steps i can see ads while running my app on my mobile  even before publishing ??

Comment: Yes. Remember to use test settings for ads (you are not allowed to click your own ads).

Comment: i know i am not allowed to click on my own ads but how to change setting to "test setting "?is there any such option in eclipse?