# Is there a way to use Firebase Legacy console from new account

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have a project which uses instructions for the Firebase v2 but even trying to log in to https://www.firebase.com and choosing Login to Legacy Console signs me in to https://console.firebase.google.com which I believe may be happening as my account is new and I have never had an application on the Version 2 console.

So my question is if anyone knows a way to get access to the old console even with a new account?

I've searched existing questions,but they do not help in this instance including: 
[Do i need to link to legacy account in admob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479014/do-i-need-to-link-to-legacy-account-in-admob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects created on (or migrated to) the new console on https://console.firebase.google.com, will only be visible on that console. They will not (or no longer) show up on the [legacy Firebase dashboard](https://www.firebase.com).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Frank. What I was hoping for was to be able to create a project on the Legacy console. However, it appears that because my account has never used the legacy console I am unable to now do that. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: It is no longer possible to sign up in the legacy console.