# How to access legacy Firebase console for new collaborator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I found this post [Is there a way to use Firebase Legacy console from new account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031062/is-there-a-way-to-use-firebase-legacy-console-from-new-account) where it states that

> It is no longer possible to sign up in the legacy console.

But if I have been added as a collaborator on a project in the legacy console, is there any way I can access that project?

Comment: I think according to the question that you already mentioned google have already migrated to the new console on https://console.firebase.google.com and it will only be visible on that console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. The owner of the legacy project can add you via email, but if you don't have a preexisting legacy console account the auth workflow won't work. You'll just end up cycling through google logins and back to the new console.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/6stRgevwkBk